# set a custom font for a button text in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a button and I want to set a custom font to the text but I have trouble doing that.

The code is the following :

**In .xml file :**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Sample Text"/>
```

**and in styles.xml**

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/ButtonTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    </style>

<style name="ButtonTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_custom_font</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: So what does not work?

Comment: @ZUNJAE the font is not set using the above code. I updated the description

Comment: What guide are you following for setting a custom font?

Comment: I do not use a guide. I made something similar before on native android and it supposed to work also on Xamarin Android.

Comment: so you're just guessing code now?

Comment: Yep, that is the reason i asked for help. If i had a guide I wouldn't have to post a question

Comment: How about finding a guide first before asking? I got custom fonts working in my Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Did you add your font to the resources? Did you change the build type to `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: @ZUNJAE Custom fonts also works in my project, i only have problems with buttons so far

Comment: ok I apologize but I don't think giving code to people who don't put in any effort themselves is a good idea. Good luck hope you figure it out.

Comment: @lawiluk i managed to set the custom fonts for almost every text in the app(WIP). The problem I have now is releated to the buttons text

Comment: @MihaiBC if you change the font in the code-behind, will it work? Try calling `setTypeface` on your button

Comment: @lawiluk thanks, I also find a solution and updated the description of the question.

Comment: You can post the solution as answer so that more people can see it.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT the solution is moved to an answer now.

Comment: You can mark it .

Comment: I am unable to mark it for the moment, it says "You can accept your answer tomorrow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of of creating a different style fontFamily should be used in the button style and the code should look like this.

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_custom_font</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
</style>
```